# UWP + SSH.Net c# how to output ANSI string from shellstream to textbox/richeditbox with correct colouring

Tags: c#, ssh, uwp, ansi-escape, ssh.net

I'm using ssh.net in a UWP program.  I am having diffixulty getting it to output a ANSI string to a richeditbox with the correct colouring as you would see using the likes of putty. The output looks like

```
[3;J[H[2J [38;5;93m───────────────────────────────────────[0m
[39;49;1mDietPi    [0m [90m|[0m [91m[33;49;1mUpdate available[0m 
[38;5;93m───────────────────────────────────────[0m
[39;49;1mV137[0m       [90m| RPi 2 Model B (armv7l)[0m
[38;5;93m───────────────────────────────────────[0m
[39;49;1mIP Address[0m [90m| [0m
[38;5;93m───────────────────────────────────────[0m

[90m Created by : Daniel Knight[0m
[90m Web        : http://DietPi.com[0m
[90m Twitter    : http://twitter.com/dietpi_[0m
[90m Donate     : http://goo   .gl/pzISt9 [0m
[90m DietPi's web hosting is powered by: MyVirtualServer.com[0m

[1m dietpi-launcher[0m  = All the DietPi programs in one place.
[1m dietpi-config[0m    = Feature rich configuration tool for your device.
[1m dietpi-software[0m  = Select optimized software for installation.
[1m dietpi-update[0m    = [91mRun now to update DietPi (from V137 to V143).[0m
[1m htop[0m             = Resource monitor.
[1m cpu[0m              = Shows CPU information and stats.
```

What are my options to get this to display correctly?  Is there a way to get richeditboxes or any other element to accept ANSI strings?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889378/looking-for-a-usercontrol-which-supports-ansi-escape-codes?

Comment: Some of the links are dead and the correct answer is a paid for piece of software.  Should also note that my question relates to the UWP

Comment: So the above is your expect outputs? What's the current outputs by your code?

Comment: Above is the current output by the code.  What i need it to do is strip the escape sequences ([1m) etc and colour correctly.  I suppose my question is can this be done easily with a UWP richeditbox or is there a better way to do it?